# Merge Tags: [deployment] and [deploy]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-merge

I propose merging these tags.  [deployment] has ~ 350 tagged questions and should be primary.  [deploy] has about 70 and can be a synonym.  I just don't have the rep to propose this directly myself.

If anyone with rep is willing to do this, we can let the normal tag review process handle voting.

Comment: Which tag are you proposing should win? It seems like it should be `[deployment]`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I think.  Thanks!

Comment: This merge is completed.

Comment: thanks so much!

Comment: don't forget to accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've proposed that `[deploy]` should get re-tagged to `[deployment]`. <s>Let the votes decide.</s> This one seems like a no-brainer and I discovered I can unilaterally approve synonyms. I've gone ahead and merged these tags.

Comment: Apparently "[I] do not have the required score on this tag to vote for this tag synonym", but I agree they're the same!

Comment: Also underprivileged to vote, but I agree.